# How to Run nginx in docker as non-root user

Tags: docker, nginx

One way to get this done is :
http://pjdietz.com/2016/08/28/nginx-in-docker-without-root.html

With this approach we need to know or force to run nginx with USER name specified in Dockerfile.

But, nginx docker container is created as part of swarm(service) with a specific user name, which I don't know in advance. So specifying USER name in Dockerfile is not an option..
How to run nginx in a docker service under a specified user which is not known in advance.?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried to run the non-root image from Nginx Inc.? https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx-unprivileged

Comment: and this answer is why i love browsing random stackoverflow questions.. i didn't even knew this existed.

Comment: This answer could use some explanation. At least I know I would appreciate more.

Comment: @mkorbi, thanks for the response.. infact I looked at it..it also sets the USER to 101 in its core Dockerfile 

Comment: From the github page readme:
`
This Dockerfile creates an NGINX Docker image that runs NGINX as a non root, unprivileged user. Notable differences with respect to the official NGINX Docker image include:

The default NGINX listen port is now 8080 instead of 80.
The default NGINX user directive in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf has been removed.
The default NGINX PID has been moved from /var/run/nginx.pid to /tmp/nginx.pid.
Change *_temp_path variables to /tmp/*.
`

Comment: If you use this image do not forget write `pid        /var/run/nginx.pid` into your nginx.conf file